# sql server 2008 - non-integer constant in ORDER BY Clause

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-order-by, constants, upgrade

Upgrade advisor says

> "Non-integer constants are not allowed in the `ORDER BY` clause in 90 or
>   later compatibility mode".

But, when I try the below statement in `SQL Server 2008`, it works just fine. So, my questions is - What exactly is a non-integer constant?

```
select 
    POS_NO
    ,EMP_NO
    ,ORG_NAME
    ,EMP_LAST_NAME + ', ' + EMP_FIRST_NAME AS "Name" 
FROM 
    dbo.MyEmpTable 
ORDER BY
    "Name"
```

Comment: It should be just `ORDER BY Name` - no double quotes. The `ORDER BY` clause needs to refer to a **columns** in your `SELECT` - even if that's a column made up from various bits.

Comment: My question is, if MS says "Non-integer columns are NOT allowed...", doesn't it mean it will throw a compile error or the query fails execution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the `MSDN` have to say about character constant that are in a sense the `non-integer constant`

> Character string constants are enclosed in single quotation marks and
>   include alphanumeric characters (a-z, A-Z, and 0-9) and special
>   characters, such as exclamation point (!), at sign (@), and number
>   sign (#). Character string constants are assigned the default
>   collation of the current database, unless the COLLATE clause is used
>   to specify a collation. Character strings typed by users are evaluated
>   through the code page of the computer and are translated to the
>   database default code page if it is required.

1) Non-integer constants are ... constants that are not integer number.

Example: 
`'string1'` represents a string constant

`0x01` represents a varbinary constant

`{ts '2015-02-26 06:00:00'}` represents a datetime constant

`1.23` represents a numeric constants

2) So single quotes are used to define a string constants / character string constants **but** SQL Server allows also to use single quotation marks use also as column identifier delimiter:

```
SELECT ... expression AS 'Column1'
FROM ...
```

In this context is clear that `'Column1'` is a column identifier **but** when used in ORDER BY : `ORDER BY 'Column1'`  it generates confusion because SQL Server doesn't knows if it represents a string literal (character string constant) or it represents a column identifier / column name.

3) SQL Server allows to use use integer constants in ORDER BY thus `SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC FROM ... ORDER BY 2`. In this case `2` is the index's of column `ColB`. Also, if you want to sort by `ColB` and `ColC` you could use `ORDER BY 2, 3`. Usage of column's index is considered to be bad practice.

4) In this case I would use

```
ORDER BY EMP_LAST_NAME + ', ' + EMP_FIRST_NAME
```