# Non-integer constants in the ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Upgrade advisor says:

> Non-integer constants are not allowed in the `ORDER BY` clause in 90 or later compatibility mode".

But, when I try the below statement in `SQL Server 2008`, it works just fine. So, my questions is: What exactly is a non-integer constant?

```
SELECT
    COALESCE( fi.Payee, -1 ) AS 'Payee',
    COALESCE( p.ProvNo, '' ) AS 'ProviderNo'
FROM
    dbo.tbl_Emp
ORDER BY
    'Payee',
    'ProviderNo'
```

Comment: It should be just ORDER BY Name - no double quotes. The ORDER BY clause needs to refer to a columns in your SELECT - even if that's a column made up from various bits. as mentioned by @Marc_s in this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414055/sql-server-2008-non-integer-constant-in-order-by-clause)

Comment: Removed `Mysql` tag because error message clearly says it is `Sql server`

Comment: In `sql server 2012` i got this error **A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position N**

Comment: Do you have SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS ON? Do you perhaps mean "AS [Payee]" and "AS [ProviderNo]", and thus "ORDER BY [Payee], [ProviderNo]"?

Comment: Why use quotes at all?

Answer (score 0):

**`Integer constants`** are represented by a string of numbers that are not enclosed in quotation marks and do not contain decimal points. integer constants must be whole numbers; they cannot contain decimals.

The following are examples of **`Integer constants`**:

```
1894 
2
```

You have mentioned  **`Non-Integer Constants`** in '' double quotes in your Query

Refer this **`MSDN`** link for [Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem in a Spring Boot context. I created a native query for a Postgres database with jpa.

This query produces an **non-integer constant in ORDER BY** exception.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM farm.cow o WHERE o.id > :uuid ORDER BY 'id' FETCH FIRST :limit ROWS ONLY ")
List<Cow> findCows(@Param("uuid") UUID String, @Param("limit") int limit);
```

To solve this exception I just change the ORDER BY 'id' to -> ORDER BY \"id\" . This approach fixed my problem.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM farm.cow o WHERE o.id > :uuid ORDER BY \"id\" FETCH FIRST :limit ROWS ONLY ")
List<Cow> findCows(@Param("uuid") UUID String, @Param("limit") int limit);
```

Comment: I don't see why you need quotes in the first place.