# Non-integer constant in GROUP BY

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, psql

I have the following line of code that is supposed to build a Pandas `DataFrame` from a SQL query:

```
query_epd = pandas.read_sql_query("SELECT 'Department', COUNT('LastName') FROM thestaff.employees GROUP BY 'Department'", engine)
```

Yet when I run my code this line gives me the error:

```
SyntaxError: non-integer constant in GROUP BY
LINE 1: ...OUNT('LastName') FROM thestaff.employees GROUP BY 'Departmen...
                                                             ^
```

I don't see where or how I am using constants, integer or not, and this is a very standard query for me on MSSQL, but running under PostgreSQL and Pandas this query is not valid. What is wrong with my query?

Comment: does selectitg * top 10 work? and if yes what does it look like?

Comment: `'Department'` is a constant.  Column names get double quoted or unquoted, not single quoted

Comment: You are using single quotes which are simply strings.  I consider this a typo and vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

The single quotes around the identifiers turn them to literal strings, which is probably not what you want. You should write this query as:

```
SELECT department, COUNT(*) no_emp
FROM thestaff.employees 
GROUP BY department
```

If your identifiers are case-sensitive, then you need to surround them with double quotes (this is the SQL standard, which Postgres complies to).

Note that I changed `COUNT(lastname)` to `COUNT(*)`: unless you have `null` values in the `lastname` column, this is equivalent, and more efficient. I also gave an alias to this column in the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

This link might be helpful [Non-integer constants in the ORDER BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734516/non-integer-constants-in-the-order-by-clause) they explain what this error is and when it occurs